# py command breaks in ps1 but not in PowerShell terminal

Tags: python, powershell, python-venv, invoke-command

The `py -3 -m venv venv` command works when typed manually into a Powershell terminal, but breaks when called from a ps1 script.

What specifically must be changed in the code below in order for the `setup.ps1` script to successfully run the `py -3 -m venv venv` command when the `setup.ps1` is called from outside using the `Invoke-Command -FilePath setup.ps1` or a similar replacement command?

The contents of the `setup.ps1` command are:

```
py -3 -m venv venv
```

The command that calls `setup.ps1` including the error together look like:

```
PS C:\path\to\dir\containing_setup_py> Invoke-Command -FilePath setup.ps1
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -FilePath setup.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

PS C:\path\to\dir\containing_setup_py>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `Invoke-Command`? Just do `.\setup.ps1`

Comment: It should work  with just `.\setup.ps1` if you specify `shell: pwsh`